# Report does not display refreshed data on Power BI - SSAS tabular model

Tags: powerbi, report, ssas, refresh, tabular

We have a SSAS that retrieves data from a MySQL using a scheduled job, which invokes the Refresh command with the "**full**" refresh type (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/refresh-command-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allv...

This job started failing due to "out of memory" and "MySQL: timeout reading communication packets" errors.

So I changed the refresh type to "**automatic**" and worked fine, since adding more memory is currently not possible. The job finishes, and after manually updating the dataset in powerbi.com, new dates appear in the reports' filters, as if new data is available, but it is not shown:
[image: powerbi.com screenshot]

If I change the filter to display data from march, it works (all new data is from april and may).

I tried executing the refresh command using types "calculated" and "add", but the model has calculation partitions and didn't worked. I don't know exactly what "clearValues" does, so I didn´t try it.

Also on-premises data gateway is updated to the latest version.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic processing might have some issues when SSAS tries automatically identify objects that need to be processed and what type of processing is needed.

It seems that the dimension table with dates is been handled but the related fact table is not.
If you have the option, you could set full processing as separate steps. For example, do full processing to dimensions on the first step and then full processing to fact tables on another step. Lastly do calculate (aka. recalc) to the whole cube. That will save some amount of memory. If not enough though, you could set different steps for each fact table. Remember to do calculate at the end.

Comment: Thank you, it was a good strategy. After three attempts it worked, the previous 2 failed returning this error: **'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] MySQL: Got timeout reading communication packets.** What could it be?

Comment: I'm not sure, it might be something specific to MySQL (I'm not familiar with MySQL). If that's a recurring problem search for posts with similar error.